# No Bluetooth Found: Plug in a dongle to use bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I am running on the latest version of Ubuntu, and just this morning I got notified of software updates, and so I installed the updates.

I had been using bluetooth with my speakers so I know that it didn't need a dongle, however, after the update, this just appeared at my bluetooth settings, and won't let me turn my bluetooth on anymore. The bluetooth icon is still there on the upper right, however it is unresponsive. It gives me the option to turn it on, but it won't.

[image: Bluetooth setting and upper right icon- view here]

This is what rfkill list outputs:

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

1: phy0: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I noticed it lists no bluetooth unlike the other thread similar to this one.

Comment: Please include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it happened, but I ran a lot of updating codes and etc, it had no immediate effect, but after letting my laptop rest for a few hours, the bluetooth just went back to normal.
I suspect it's specifically a problem with my laptop. I'm so sorry for the inconvenience.